# How to move text cursor to previous position after pressing "Home" key, etc.?

Tags: windows, text-editors, text-cursor

If I'm typing something (this question for example), and I press <kbd>Home</kbd>, and the blinking line, letting me know where I'm typing, goes to the front of the line.  To go back to the end, I can just press <kbd>End</kbd>.

What if I'm editing what I've already written?  For example, if I want to **bold** a word. I first go to that word (using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys, then press "**".  I then slip, pressing <kbd>Home</kbd>.

How can I go back to the last place I was typing before I pressed <kbd>Home</kbd>,<kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or  <kbd>Page Down</kbd>?

Comment: the answer to that question depends entirely on the "editor" you are using. vim for example has a a list of jump positions.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and Microsoft Office (someone removed those tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> *in Chrome*.

This is assuming you wish to return to where the cursor was before you "slipped". If you want to return to where you started at the first time you pressed home, that you will have to use the arrow keys.

Comment: I'm not looking for a one button solution...  I'll wait to see if anyone else has an answer.

Comment: The good news is that I suggested a two button solution...?

Comment: What?  is that a joke?  BTW, I'm looking for a one step solution.

Comment: CTRL+Z is one step. Maybe I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. My understanding is you are typing some text and you make a typo by hitting a positioning key (Home, End, PgUp, PgDn) and wish to return to where you were previously typing. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  CTRL+Z undoes any **changes** that are made to the text or document.  Moving the mouse cursor isn't considered a change.

Comment: Yes, I see now that it works in Chrome, but may not necessarily work elsewhere. Updated my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Word, the shortcut   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>F5</kbd> technically returns your cursor to the last **editing** position.  But ever since Word 2003, it has moved your cursor to the last position, period.

Try that.

This also works in Visual Studios.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will get you back to exactly where you were.
<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> generally preserve the horizontal position of the cursor, so pressing the opposite key should work. If not, Undo-Redo will still work.